# WiX: application installed can only work when runas administrator in windows7

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am a beginner of Wix, I make a msi, and install it in windows7,but the application
only work correctly when runas administrator. Can somebody give me some suggest?

Comment: Do you mean that the setup needs to run with administrative privileges? Or the application that has been installed by your setup?

Comment: The application that has been installed by your setup need administrative privileges to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a verbose log file (see the command line options topic in the MSI SDK) and see what the actual install error is.

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. the process of installation is successful, the application installed by setup package need adim privilege to run correctely.

Comment: The issue you described above means there is a bug somewhere in your installation. The Windows Installer will elevate correctly for you. However, if you have a bug in your setup (usually a buggy Custom Action) then things can still fail. A verbose log file will point to the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does it run on Vista?
For installation it is common to be run by administrator - the application itself should be able to run without admin privileges and this requires dedicated work.